# How to get the number of checked checkboxes in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started learning React not so long ago. Decided to make some kind of "life checklist" as one of my beginner projects. I have been using Functional Components in the core.

FYI:

1. I have data.js as an array of objects where "action", "emoji" and unique ID are stored.
2. I import it into my App.js.

```
const App = () => {
  //Looping over data
  const items = data.map((item) => {
    return (
      <ChecklistItem action={item.action} emoji={item.emoji} key={item.id} />
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <StyledHeading>Life Checklist</StyledHeading>
      <StyledApp>{items}</StyledApp>
      <h2>Overall number: {data.length}</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is my `<ChecklistItem/>` component:

```
const ChecklistItem = ({ action, emoji }) => {
  //State
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  //Event Handlers
  const changeHandler = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <StyledChecklistItem isActive={isActive}>
      <input type="checkbox" checked={isActive} onChange={changeHandler} />
      <StyledEmoji role="img">{emoji}</StyledEmoji>
      <StyledCaption>{action}</StyledCaption>
    </StyledChecklistItem>
  );
};

export default ChecklistItem;
```

I would be satisfied with the functionality so far, but I need to show how many "active" checklist items were chosen in the parent `<App/>` component like "You have chosen X items out of `{data.length}`. How can I achieve this?

I assume that I need to lift the state up, but cannot understand how to implement this properly yet.

Comment: Create the state inside the `App` and pass a function to `ChecklistItem` instead of using state _within_ the `ChecklistItem`. That way you collect all the states in one location and you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by simply creating a state for storing this particular `count` of active items.

To do that, you would need to update your `<App/>` component to something like this

```js
const App = () => {
  const [activeItemsCount, setActiveItemsCount] = useState(0);

  //Looping over data
  const items = data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <ChecklistItem
        key={index}
        action={item.action}
        emoji={item.emoji}
        setActiveItemsCount={setActiveItemsCount}
      />
    );
  });

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Life Checklist</h1>
      <div>{items}</div>
      <div>Active {activeItemsCount} </div>
      <h2>Overall number: {data.length}</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And then in your `<ChecklistItem />` component, you would need to accept that `setActiveItemsCount` function so that you can change the state of the `activeItemsCount`.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const ChecklistItem = ({ action, emoji, setActiveItemsCount }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const changeHandler = () => {
    setIsActive(!isActive);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isActive) {
      setActiveItemsCount((prevCount) => {
        if (prevCount !== 0) {
          return prevCount - 1;
        }

        return prevCount;
      });
    }

    if (isActive) {
      setActiveItemsCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }
  }, [isActive, setActiveItemsCount]);

  return <input type="checkbox" checked={isActive} onChange={changeHandler} />;
};

export default ChecklistItem;
```

By using the `useEffect` and the checks for `isActive` and `0` value, you can nicely increment or decrement the active count number by pressing the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
const data = [
   { action: '1', emoji: '1', id: 1 },
   { action: '2', emoji: '2', id: 2 },
   { action: '3', emoji: '3', id: 3 },
];

const ChecklistItem = ({ action, emoji, isActive, changeHandler }) => {
   return (
      <div isActive={isActive}>
         <input type="checkbox" checked={isActive} onChange={changeHandler} />
         <div>{emoji}</div>
         <div>{action}</div>
      </div>
   );
};

const PageContainer = () => {
   const [checkedItemIds, setCheckedItemIds] = useState([]);

   function changeHandler(itemId) {
      if (checkedItemIds.indexOf(itemId) > -1) {
         setCheckedItemIds((prev) => prev.filter((i) => i !== itemId));
      } else {
         setCheckedItemIds((prev) => [...prev, itemId]);
      }
   }

   const items = data.map((item) => {
      const isActive = checkedItemIds.indexOf(item.id) > -1;
      return (
         <ChecklistItem
            isActive={isActive}
            changeHandler={() => changeHandler(item.id)}
            action={item.action}
            emoji={item.emoji}
            key={item.id}
         />
      );
   });
   return (
      <div className="bg-gray-100">
         <div>{items}</div>
         <h2>
            You have chosen {checkedItemIds.length} items out of {data.length}
         </h2>
      </div>
   );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When data is used by a child component, but the parent needs to be aware of it for various reasons, that should be state in the parent component. That state is then handed to the child as props.

One way to do this would be to initialize your parent component with a piece of state that was an array of boolean values all initialized to `false`. Map that state into the checkbox components themselves and hand `isActive` as a prop based on that boolean value. You should then also hand the children a function of the parent that will change the state of the boolean value at a certain index of that array.

Here's a bit of a contrived example:

```
  // Parent.tsx

  const [checkBoxes, setCheckboxes] = useState(data.map(data => ({
    id: data.id,
    action: data.action,
    emoji: data.emoji
    isActive: false,
  })));

  const handleCheckedChange = (i) => {
    setCheckboxes(checkBoxes => {
      checkBoxes[i].isActive = !checkBoxes[i].isActive;
      return checkBoxes;
    })
  } 

  return(
    checkBoxes.map((item, i) => 
      <ChecklistItem 
        action={item.action} 
        emoji={item.emoji} 
        key={item.id} 
        index={i} 
        isActive={item.isActive} 
        handleChange={handleCheckedChange} 
     />
    )
  );


  // CheckListItem.tsx
  const CheckListItem = ({ action, emoji, index, isActive, handleChange }) => (
      <StyledChecklistItem isActive={isActive}>
        <input type="checkbox" checked={isActive} onChange={() => handleChange(index)} />
        <StyledEmoji role="img">{emoji}</StyledEmoji>
        <StyledCaption>{action}</StyledCaption>
      </StyledChecklistItem>
  )
```